# Best memory management practice for blocks and completion handlers

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I have the following code in my app, and there is a memory leak with the 'dict' object. So I have a few questions about the best practice for this after the code:

```
// Convert JSON to dict
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // If error return nil
                    if (error)
                        completion(nil, [self handleSerializationError:error]);
                    else if (![UsefulFunctions objectContainsData:dict[@"data"]])
                        completion(nil, NO);
                    // No error then return dict
                    else
                        completion(dict, NO);
                });
```

About the code: The completion handler passes back the dict object which is then used to create core data entities (hence the main thread) based upon the calling function. The data being serialised is from an NSURLConnection. So the questions are as follows:

1) Is this the correct practice for passing back data in a completion handler?

2) Which function should take care of the memory management, should it be the calling class?

3) Is it worth wrapping this in an auto-release pool, or is that not how they are supposed to be used (kind of a separate question).

4) Can anyone see any obvious reasons from this function alone why the dict is retained, or is it purely down to the calling class?

Thanks for any help

EDIT (Whole Function), just to confirm I am using ARC and this function is called from the main thread:

```
- (void)downloadJSONFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id object, BOOL retry))completion
{
    // Check URL
    if (url)
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString *authToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token %@", [UsefulFunctions returnActiveAPIKey]];
        [request setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        // Create an asynch request, don't want to hold up main queue
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[self operationQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
        {
            // If data exists
            if (data)
            {
                // Convert JSON to dict
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // If error return nil
                    if (error)
                        completion(nil, [self handleSerializationError:error]);
                    else if (![UsefulFunctions objectContainsData:dict[@"data"]])
                        completion(nil, NO);
                    // No error then return dict
                    else
                        completion(dict, NO);
                });

            }
            // If error
            else if (connectionError)
            {
                //NSLog(@"Connection Error: %@, Code: %lu", connectionError.description, (long)connectionError.code);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Return nil
                    completion(nil, [self handleConnectionError:connectionError]);
                });
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: In either case, the code posted shouldn't leak.  Or do captured references require an explicit `release` under MRC?  (I've never used blocks under MRC.)

Comment: Can you post the whole method? Is the completion method sync or async?

Comment: Hi sorry, yes I'm using ARC, will post the whole function in an edit.

Comment: What makes you think there is a memory leak?

Comment: Just using profiles, running the whole app the only memory leaks detected are with this function. It has 269 of them so they are fairly frequent by the looks. It actually has an issue with NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]; which is why I was asking questions about the best practice about releasing the data (is it this class or the returned class which should handle it).

Comment: There's no leak in the code in the question, and there is no "best practice" for releasing the data - it's not even possible to release things in ARC, except by setting them to nil. It's entirely possible you're seeing leaks in NSJSONSerialization, in which case there's nothing you can do, or there's something in `UsefulFunctions` that you're not showing here. Are you profiling with a debug build or a release build? Can you show the instruments output you're concerned about?

Comment: @jrturton I am using a debug build, and I think you are correct it's coming from within the NSJSONSerialization so I will not worry about it for now. If it starts causing any major issues I will re-address the issue, I mainly wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything obviously wrong with the block. Thanks for the help